# JVM behaviour on the object of a class implement serializable interface

Tags: java, serialization, jvm

My question is when we have class which implements interface serializable and when we send object of that class over the network, does JVM make copy of object into memory or how JVM behave by meaning of "persist the state" of an object.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: It copies all the data of the data in such a way that an object can be deserialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interface serializable is a marker interface, it indicate to JVM that objects of this class (which implements serialized) can be persisted to any stream (file or pushed on network socket). Whenever asked for serialization JVM writes the state of that object on the given stream and original object is kept or discarded will depend of the scope (life) of that object; so no question of JVM making making copy in memory or not.